# Zoom and scale are overlapping text

Tags: css, zooming, scale, overlapping

I am trying to grow the image using scale and zoom on hover, but it is overlapping the text on hover, as shown in this image: http://private.teunstrik.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Schermafbeelding-2017-05-13-om-18.16.02.png

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Code:

```
div.item  {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item img {
   -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
}


.item img:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(2,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,1);
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using another class that controls the image.

```
.zoom-image {
         width: 100%;
     height:75px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item img {
   -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
}


.item img:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(2,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,1);
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

And then, for example:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="zoom-image">
    <img src="http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_small_1.jpg">
 </img>
    </div>
     <span class="caption">Test image
    <br><a href="#">Bekijk...</a></span>
</div>
```